# Adding and Multiplying Polynomials Recursively

Tags: polynomials, recursive-algorithms

What theorem can be used to recursively multiply two polynomials together?

Is there another theorem that uses recursion to add together two polynomials recursively?

I'm looking for something that accomplishes these things in much the same way that Horner's method can be used to evaluate a polynomial.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

For multiplication, maybe you are looking for Karatsuba's algorithm? See section 1.3 of this book:

http://www.loria.fr/~zimmerma/mca/pub226.html

(Addition is also mentioned, but I'm not sure there's much useful that can be said about polynomial addition).